# "Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters": make it even

Tags: string, hex

Some close-minded program that I need to feed dummy data to, would only accept a string of "only hex characters" as input:

```
[Error:] Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character
```

So I tried sending some hex string, such as `Í Í`. Unfortunately, now I get

```
[Error:] Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters
```

I thought that obviously, doubling the string would produce twice the number of characters, thus satisfying the constraint: `Í Í Í Í`. But no.

```
[Error:] Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters
```

Is there a way to produce a string with an odd number of hexadecimal characters?

Comment: A "hex character" likely refers to 0-9A-F, a hex string being a series of them.

Comment: Ah, good. I tried "------", "xxxxxx", but not "FFFFFF". Got it working, thanks.